# EJS import (with Express) not rendering partials

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to render my partials into views but I keep getting the error

```
Error: Could not find the include file "(&#39;partials/header&#39;)"
```

My files structure is like so:

```
-MAIN FOLDER
 -controllers
   -userController
   -staticPagesController
   -postsController
 -models
    posts
    users
 -public
    stylesheets
 -views
    user
      all user ejs files
    post
      all post ejs files
    site
      all staticpage ejs files
    partials
      all partials
 -index.js
```

I tried adding my partials folder to each view subfolder, but it didn't help anything.
I also thought maybe my controllers weren't seeing the path properly and added ejs = require(`ejs`) to each controller path but it didn't fix it either.

my views look like this:

```
<%- include ('partials/header') %>

<h1>Homepage</h1>
```

and my index.js looks like this:

```
//Application global constants
const express    = require(`express`);
const mongoose   = require(`mongoose`);
const bodyParser = require(`body-parser`);
const ejs        = require('ejs');
const _          = require(`lodash`);      
//Initiate Express
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(`public`));
//Initiate EJS engine
app.set(`view engine`, `ejs`);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
//Initiate body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//Set express static files


//ROUTING
staticPages = require(`./controllers/staticPageController`);
postPages = require(`./controllers/postController`);
userPages = require(`./controllers/userController`);
```

Comment: <%- includes("../partials/header") %> is the correct link. I did try this before but it seems that if there is a space after "includes" it will actually include the space + ("../partials/header") as a link (yes the brackets too!) as you can see in the error that I supplied => "(&#39;../partials/header&#39;)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try to add below code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Also include the header like(Remove the space specially):

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'views' folder declaration

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```